# Web Crawling using BS4 returning incorrect html content

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to find some statistics regarding the GPA, GRE and work-experience of students admitted to a particular university, by **scraping** data from Yocket. While my code is working correctly for the first page(https://yocket.in/applications-admits-rejects/588-new-york-university/2), but when i am trying to crawl the later pages when you click the below navigation bar(https://yocket.in/applications-admits-rejects/588-new-york-university/2?page=2),The code didn't work. On analysis i found that the HTML content received for the later pages are coming to be incorrect i.e. the html content received are corresponding to some other page. Also,the content received is incorrect for page=3,page=4 and so on. The content crawled is correct only for page=1.This URL is for NYU, however this behavior on incorrect content being received on page=2 is same for all other university's URL
However, I want status for admits only. So, need to find a way to navigate through different pages in page 2. Url would be /2?page= section.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page_num=2
url="https://yocket.in/applications-admits-rejects/588-new-york-university/2?page=" + str(page_num) 
page = requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content)
print(soup.prettify())
```

Answer (score 0):

It is giving warning because no parser is explicitly defined just pass *features = "lxml"* to the BeautifulSoup constructor and it will solve the issue.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page_num=2
url="https://yocket.in/applications-admits-rejects/588-new-york-university/2?page=" + str(page_num) 
page = requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,features = "lxml")
print(soup.prettify())
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: The problem here is that https://yocket.in/applications-admits-rejects/588-new-york-university/1 corresponds start page of  all rejects, https://yocket.in/applications-admits-rejects/588-new-york-university/2 - Corresponds to admit to that university, https://yocket.in/applications-admits-rejects/588-new-york-university/4 - Corresponds to the status of interested in university. However, I want status for admits only. So, need to find a way to navigate throw different pages in /2?page= section.

Comment: For sections under page, you can use different tags to get contents from them.

Comment: But the issue is each page has 20 entries only. I want all the entries, so for that purpose,  yocket.in/applications-admits-rejects/588-new-york-university/2 will allow me to get only data points.In order to get more,i need to navigate through : /2?page=2,3...

Comment: Yes. Your url was correct for the same. Just add features ="lxml" check edited code. It's working fine for me.

Comment: The code is scrapping some HTML, however, the content is corresponding to some other page(perhaps, home page). There is no content for GPA, GRE etc

Comment: It says you are not authorised to access that location. I took screenshot of the page using selenium ant it redirects to login page. you need to login first from your code and then go to the page.